# PHP - Calling database class from another class

Tags: php

I've recently encountered an error in my code:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$connection' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in
```

From what I've googled the issue is not setting public/private/protected before, or not creating the database connection in the construct function.

The database connection class code:

```
 class databaseConnection {


    //Database information
    protected $mysqliUser = "";
    protected $mysqliHost = "localhost";
    protected $mysqlipass = "";
    protected $mysqlidbname = "";
    public $con;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->con = new mysqli($this->mysqliHost,$this->mysqliUser,$this-
        >mysqlipass,$this->mysqlidbname); 

    }

}
```

A snippet of the class code that is receiving the error:

```
private $conn;
    $conn = new databaseConnection;
```

Any help to point me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Remove `public $this->connection` and your `return` statement in your `__construct`. `__construct` method can't return a value.

Comment: It sure can, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @cale_b yeah hahaha, just easier to paste snippets rather than having to remove private information.

Comment: @Marwelln ah thanks, however sadly still receiving the same error.

Comment: "Unexpected" usually means something wrong with the thing before it, but we can't see that code. (additional notes, it's arguably pointless returning as you are. And while not necessary, it's usually best practice to use parenthesis when instantiating a new class.)

Comment: @James ah, I didn't know that. I've updated the database code, and thank you for the tip of best practice.

Comment: I guess $connection is now $con? as I can't see the variable mentioned in the error. Can you show more of the file with the error? Seems odd you have "private" declaration then calling another class right after

Comment: @James above the private declaration is just the class creation class createSession

Comment: The problem with posting incomplete code is that the error you're asking for help with is a syntax error, so it depends on precisely what the code looks like. Try to create a [mcve] - something that you can run, and get the same error, but doesn't include details you don't want to share. Otherwise, we're really just guessing, and that's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Also, note that this has nothing to do with the database class you've shared. PHP hasn't even got as far as trying to run your code, because it can't understand your source code to compile it. So you don't need to look at anything other than that one file where the syntax error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> above the private declaration is just the class creation class
>   createSession

In which case your `$conn = new databaseConnection;` either needs visibility, or should be in a method. Hard to tell which without seeing all the class and the odd indentation you have.

So put that in the method it belongs in (perhaps the constructor?) or set it to private, protected, or public - whichever it was intended for.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

It really works..

> **connect.php**

```
class DBConnect {
    private static $connection;
    private static $host = "localhost";
    private static $user = "root";
    private static $pwd = "";
    private static $dbname = "yourDBName";

    public static function connect() {
        $host = self::$host;
        $user = self::$user;
        $pwd = self::$pwd;
        $dbname = self::$dbname;

        self::$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $dbname) or die('Error connecting..');
        return self::$connection;
    }
}
```

> **myclass.php**

```
require_once('connect.php');

class MyClass {
    private $connObj;

    public function __construct() {     
        $this->connObj = DBConnect::connect();
    }

    public function select() {
        $conn = $this->connObj;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        $res = $query->fetch_assoc();
        // your code..
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->select();
```

Hope, this code snippet works fine for you. :) :)

Comment: Well apart from this not really helping the OP from fixing their own code ... You shouldn't use `die()` in such places, should be handled better. Especially with uninformative output which is bad for users. You shouldn't use raw SQL, parametrise instead. You shouldn't `select *` (debatable, but meh)...+ other things...sorry but this is old code :( "it really works" - so does beating a screw with a hammer, but, screwdrivers ftw ;)

Comment: Thanks @james but OP main issue was to retireval of connection object from other class. Old is Gold and.. anyway i know about SQL Injection and it's best practices.. it was not rather necessary to include all the stuff just tried to help OP to sort out his main problem

Comment: well that's why I didn't downvote ;) old is not gold imo, easy to write, and nothing new to learn, but maintenance nightmare and hard to work with in the long run. :)